# Unity mp4 video not playing in windows build but works in mac

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity game that contains a video to be played multiple times throughout the game (every 90 seconds). This works fine on Mac but the video won't play on windows. I don't think its a code error as all the other code in the function that plays the video runs fine.

The video is an mp4, with H.264 codec so it should be compatible with windows.

#### **Settings for video clip**

[image]

#### **Settings for videoPlayer**

[image]

Here's the code just in case anyone can spot anything wrong with it, but the optionsButton and notebookButton do become inactive on windows, its just the video doesn't play.

```
void Start()
{

    InvokeRepeating("Murder", 90, 90);
}

void Murder()
{ 
        CloseNotebook();
        CloseOptions();

        StartCoroutine(playVideo());
    }
}

IEnumerator playVideo() {

    optionsButton.SetActive(false);
    notebookButton.SetActive(false);

    videoPlayer.Play();
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(timeToStop);
    videoPlayer.Stop();

    optionsButton.SetActive(true);
    notebookButton.SetActive(true);

}
```

Comment: in general it seems there are potentially multiple routines running at a time ...

Comment: Does it play in Windows media player?

Comment: @ephb yes just not in the actual game.

Comment: I was asking this at this should rule out codec issues. Almost everything plays in VLC but if it plays in Windows media player, then your system has the right codecs for it and it is more likely with your setup or script.
Yes take your script of and enable "Play on Awake" to see if it works then.

Comment: Just tested with play on awake and without script and it still won't play, not sure what this could be as windows media player worked fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can you save the video on the Windows harddrive (outside the game) and test just the video file?  (ie. In windows media player).
2. If you can, and windows media player doesn't work,  Can you download a player like https://www.videolan.org/vlc/ and see if the video will play within this player?

From what I can tell it is supposed to be H264 so your setting looks right.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html

3. The other thing you can try is playing another file... like a different MP4 in your game after verifying it works on that same windows computer you are having trouble with.   Then you can at least narrow it down to your particular file.

Comment: It plays fine in windows media player, however when I tried with a different mp4 that video played fine, however that one didn't have any audio whereas my one does, so I made the audio and video play separately and now it works :) Thanks

Comment: there are a few articles on the audio not working such as setting the audio volume to 1.0f etc.  Good luck.   // Set mode to Audio Source.
videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
 
// We want to control one audio track with the video player
videoPlayer.controlledAudioTrackCount = 1;
 
// We enable the first track, which has the id zero
videoPlayer.EnableAudioTrack(0, true);
 
// ...and we set the audio source for this track
videoPlayer.SetTargetAudioSource(0, audioSource);